# Copy only specific rows from one table to another in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, text, row

I have mysql database with users that contains their email, icq, skype, etc. and text file that contains some of the email address from database on each line.
What I want to do is copy entire row from database of every user that is in the text file from one table to another.

Here is my code:

```
$filename="123.txt";
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 
$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

$id = 1;
while($id <= 500){
$user = $array[$id];
$copy = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newusers SELECT * FROM oldusers WHERE email='$user'");
echo "$user<br>";
$id++;
}
```

But it insert nothing into new table. But when I use code like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO newusers SELECT * FROM oldusers WHERE email='emailofuser@gmail.com'");
```

It works just fine.
How I should manage my code so it will read data from text and use it in SQL?

Comment: Before you take another step, see sql injection, deprecated mysql_ api, and prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with code:

```
$filename="123.txt";   
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$ex = preg_split('/\s+/', $contents);
foreach ($ex as $user) {   
  echo "$user";
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO newusers SELECT * FROM oldusers WHERE email='{$user}'");
  }    
fclose($handle);
```

Problem was that after reading text file line by line I was getting a space after every email so output was like:

```
some@thing.com any@thing.com goo@gle.net etc.
```

And because of this space after every email SQL though emails were different. But with calling preg_split() I removed spaces and everything is working. I hope I wrote it understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of while you could use foreach.

```
foreach ($array as $user) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO newusers SELECT * FROM oldusers WHERE email='{$user}'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tip, but it still do not want to insert data into table.

Comment: Please do `echo mysql_error().'<br />'` instead of `echo $user.'<br />'` so we can see what is the error that you get. It might be due to the autoincrement value. If so you should update your code to: `"INSERT INTO newusers (list, of, fields, except, id) SELECT FROM list, of, fields, except, id oldusers WHERE email='{$user}'"`. I am assuming that `id` is the autoincremented row.